# How to prove the continuity of the metric function?

Tags: metric-spaces

Given a metric space $(X,d)$, how to prove that the function $d \colon X \times X \to \mathbf{R}$ is continuous?

If we take any two arbitrary real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a < b$, then we need to show that the set $d^{-1} (a,b)$ given by

$$ d^{-1} (a,b) :=  \{ (x, y) \in X \times X | a < d(x,y) < b \} $$

is open in the product topology on $X \times X$.

A basis for this product topology is the collection of all cartesian products of open balls in $(X,d)$.

Comment: See also:
[Is the mapping $d : X\times X \mapsto \mathbb {R}$ continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/351359),
[Metric is continuous function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1557642),
[Continuity between metric d with respect to product topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1934130).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(x,y)\in d^{-1}(a,b)$. Define $\epsilon=\frac{1}{100}\min(d(x,y)-a,b-d(x,y))$.
Then for any point $(\xi,\gamma)\in B(x,\epsilon)\times B(y,\epsilon)$, we have
$${\color{blue} d(\xi,\gamma) }\leq d(\xi,x)+d(x,y)+d(y,\gamma)<2\epsilon+d(x,y)<{\color{blue}b}$$
and
$${\color{blue} a}<d(x,y)-2\epsilon <d(\xi,\gamma)+\underbrace{ d(x,\xi)-\epsilon}_{<0}  +\underbrace{d(y,\gamma)-\epsilon}_{<0}<{\color{blue} d(\xi,\gamma)}.$$
That is to say
$$(x,y)\in B(x,\epsilon)\times B(y,\epsilon)\subseteq d^{-1}(a,b).$$

Hence any point $(x,y)\in d^{-1}(a,b)\subseteq X\times X$ is surrounded by some open set contained in $d^{-1}(a,b)$.

(After typing this answer, I realized this is EXACTLY the same as the answer by @k.stm; so thanks also to his contribution. I guess it will be hard to write a different one.)

Answer (score 27):

For $a, b ∈ ℝ$, let $(x,y) ∈ d^{-1} (a..b)$, i.e. $a < d(x,y) < b$. Now choose $ε$ such that $U_{2ε} (d(x,y)) ⊂ (a..b)$ and look at $U_ε (x) × U_ε (y)$.

For any tuple of points $(x',y') ∈ U_ε (x) × U_ε (y)$ you have
$$d(x',y') ≤ d(x',x) + d(x,y) + d(y,y') < d(x,y) + 2ε$$
as well as
$$d(x,y) ≤ d(x,x') + d(x',y') + d(y',y) < d(x',y') + 2ε$$
This means $a < d(x,y) - 2ε < d(x',y') < d(x,y) + 2ε < b$.

Therefore $U_{ε} (x) × U_{ε} (y) ⊂ d^{-1} (a..b)$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't recognize the notation, but by $(a..b)$ do you mean the set of all real numbers from $a$ to $b$ exclusive (i.e. the open interval)?

Comment: Yeah, it’s a notation introduced by Knuth, I believe. It’s quite handy. It avoids the confusion of regarding $(a,b)$ both as a tuple and as an open interval. See the [good notations thread](http://mathoverflow.net/a/42984/26710) on mathoverflow.

Comment: So in the metric space $X$, we can take any point $x, y$ such that $d(x,y)=k$ with any given $k \in R$ ?

Comment: @RopuToran No, why would you think that? In ℚ, you find no two points with distance exactly $\sqrt 2$.