# discontinuous metric

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Does there exist a discontinuous metric?

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. If we consider $X\times X$ as a metric space with the discrete metric, then $d:X\times X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$ is evidently continuous. It is possible to define a metric on $X\times X$ such that $d$ is not continuous with respect to that metric?

Comment: A metric is a continuous function from the Cartesian product of your space into the non negative reals. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287285/how-to-prove-the-continuity-of-the-metric-function)

Comment: Why is this closed and considered a duplicate of a post which does not answer this question?